# Android creating an App that clicks on other Apps

Tags: android, testing, automation

Is it possible on Android to make an App that clicks on a location (x,y) of the screen while another app is in foreground ?

i want to create an app that clicks on buttons (with a fixed x,y coordinates) of another app for automating tasks.

like to do a background service that clicks (400, 300) while the other app is running will it work?

if not, anyone have any idea on how to accomplish that? (i did it while using adb commands but i want to do it without the need of a computer)

Comment: If you get the context of running application , surely you can but how will you get? It's a nice question and deserves a upvote